# PHP Contact Form submission failed and no error message returned from: forms/contact.php

Tags: php, html

I am facing issue in my contact form, i want to send a mail using php on click on send message button i am getting error form submission failed no errors

```
<div class="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="100">

        <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="my-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>

      </div>
```

[image]

Here is my php code which i save with contact.php under forms folder.

```
<?php  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$result = "";
$error  = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name']; // Get Name value from HTML Form
$email_id = $_POST['email']; // Get Email Value
     
$to = "support@globalexpresssolutions.net"; // You can change here your Email
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // This is your subject
     
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//smtp settings
$mail->isSMTP(); // send as HTML
$mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "************"; // Your mail
$mail->Password = '************'; // Your password mail
$mail->Port = 465; //specify SMTP Port
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl\tls';                               
$mail->setFrom($email_id,$name);
$mail->addAddress('**********');
$mail->addReplyTo($email_id,$name);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject=$subject;
$mail->Body="
    <html>
        <body>
            <table style='width:600px;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:150px'><strong>Name: </strong></td>
                        <td style='width:400px'>$name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:150px'><strong>Email ID: </strong></td>
                        <td style='width:400px'>$email_id</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:150px'><strong>Message: </strong></td>
                        <td style='width:400px'>$msg</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";;
if(!$mail->send())
{
    $error = "Something went worng. Please try again.";
}
else 
{
    $result="Thanks\t" .$name. " for contacting us.";
}
```

}

?>

i have added the phpmailer files to

[image]

Please help me in resolving and understanding the issue

Comment: Is the form data actually getting sent? The error in the red box doesn't match what you have in your contact.php form

Comment: Please verify where this error message is coming from.

Comment: Actually i am new to this can u guide me how to verify it

Comment: call one more method of PhpMailer to debug the exact problem. `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`

Comment: i did it but no success i didnt find anything

Comment: the contact form is hosted on www.globalexpresssolutions.net can u guys help me out

Answer (score 0):

Your error message isn't a php error. Enable php errors on your contact.php page and show us the exact error. You can do this by going to your php.ini file and enabling all errors. Also, comment out your mail function for now just to make sure php is getting your form data.

Comment: verified it the php script is getting called kept the echo statement and printed the values its getting printed